# Why is my textbox in readonly Mode in tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm working with .net framework 4.0 ، Visual Studio 2010 and writing in c#.
in my windows form application i have a tabcontrol called tablcontrol1 and within that i have a textbox called txt_name.
in txt_name property i didn't set the ReadOnly attribute to true.
but when i start the application the txt_name which is within the tabcontrol1
is some kind of ReadOnly :
i mean it's value can't be changed and it's background-color is grey just like a ReadOnly textbox and when i put the txt_name outside of the tabcontrol1 :
it is fixed and it's not in ReadOnly mood so i guess the main problem is with the tabcontrol1.
I searcher a lot but i don't what should i do with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check [Enabled] property
also controls.Enable like the below

```
 foreach (Control ctl in tablcontrol1.Controls) ctl.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks i found the solution

Comment: My tabcontrol was unabled so i set the enabled attribute to true